# Count all eMails from a Label

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

i have create this script:

```js
function myTest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Label1");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  var countMail = 0;
  
  //get first message in first thread
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
    countMail = countMail + messages.length;
  }
  ss.getRange(1,1).setValue(countMail);
}
```

it runs nearly perfect. Here I get all eMails back which are connected with this treads (marked with Label1 or not).
Does anyone can share a simply script how I can count all eMails which are "realy" marked with the Label.

Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with your current countMail?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function labelMsgs(){
  var labels = Gmail.Users.Labels.list("me").labels;
  var lblId;
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i ++){
    if (labels[i].name == "Label1"){
      lblId = labels[i].id;
      break;
    }
  }

  var optionalArgs = {
    "labelIds" : lblId,
    "maxResults" : 200
  }

  var messages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list("me", optionalArgs).messages;
}
```

This method uses the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A200%7D) directly, for this you'll need to [enable Google Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services), it will return a list of all messages tagged with the `"Label1"` label. You can play around with `maxResults` and with the `pageToken` to see more results, but this is the general approach.

Comment: How can I do this on a delegated group email account?